# How to add image to foundation tooltip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tooltip, zurb-foundation

i'm using foundation tooltips to show the users which liked the post. For example here i need to show current user avatar:

```
span.has-tip data-tooltip="" title="#{image_tag(current_user.avatar)}"Like
```

But when I reload page i get an tooltip with:

```
<img src=
```

and nothing else. 
How should I correctly use images in tooltip?

If I call ***image_tag(current_user.avatar)*** in other place it works fine.

Comment: `image_tag` returns an image html tag (`<img src="...">`). What do you expect the `image_tag` to return or how should your `tooltip` look like?

Comment: @spickermann tooltip just should have current_user.avatar (small image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Foundation 6.2.4 you would need to specify a custom template using the `data-template` attribute (see available options at http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/tooltip.html#js-options).

This would look something like

```
   span.has-tip data-tooltip="" data-template="<div class='tooltip'>#{image_tag(current_user.avatar)}}</div>"Like
```

Coming in version 6.3 (due to be released 2 weeks from Thursday) there will be an option to allow HTML content in your tooltip directly.

Comment: How should I add few images to 1 tooltip? your answer works fine for me